# cannot call web service created in java

Tags: eclipse, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee

I'm studying now about web services in java. I created a project where I 
have a couple of web services. One of these web services, when is 
called, should interrogate database and return to me something. But, 
apparently, I can't even call my web service, and I don't know why. In the 
same time, another web services are working well.

Here's the code from my wrong web service:

```
{
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/menu")
public class MenuWebService {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Connection conn;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Menu> getMenu() {
        try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
            List<Menu> menu = new ArrayList<Menu>();
            st.execute("SELECT id_produs, nume_produs, pret, imagine, descriere FROM meniu;");
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Menu rp = new Menu(rs.getInt("id_produs"),rs.getString("nume_produs"),rs.getFloat("id_chelner"),
                                    rs.getInt("pret"),rs.getInt("descriere"));
                menu.add(rp);
            }
            st.close();
            return menu;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
}
```

This is example from working web service:

```
{
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    // Metoda apelata daca tipul media cerut este TEXT_PLAIN
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // Metoda apelata daca tipul media cerut este XML
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hellouu Jersey" + " 
    </hello>";
    }

    // Metoda apelata daca tipul media cerut este HTML
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello New Jersey" + "</h1>"
                + "<h2>" + /*DBManager.getInstance().getMenu().toString() + */"</h2></body>" + "</html> ";
    }    
}    
}
```

If you need some more information or some configuration files please 
tell me. It's my first experience with web service. I'm using Apache 
Tomcat 8.5 server and Eclipse Java Enterprise Edition.

Comment: _"I can't even call my web service"_ - Please elaborate. Nobody has any idea what this means except for you.